# Answering telephone causes 2nd activity in android app to close

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a media app with a main-activity that I use for most of the app's functions.

When I open the media player (I am using exoplayer), I open a 2nd activity (player-activity) that is dedicated to the functions involved with playing the media content.

If the phone rings while media is being played, and I answer the phone, the player-activity immediately closes (I can see the onStop() and onDestroy() functions being called).

When I hang up the phone, the main-activity is displayed and is in the state it was when it created the player-activity. Things seem to be acting as if I had pressed the back-button while in the player-activity.

I want the player-activity to remain open during the phone conversation, and then return to playing when the phone is hung up. I am already catching the phone state, and I know how to pause and restart the media based on the phone state. But, I can't figure out why the player-activity is being closed when I answer the phone.

Here is the code I'm using to start the 2nd activity:

```
val playerIntent = Intent(this, PlayerActivity::class.java)
playerIntent.putExtra("docket", event.docket as Serializable)
startActivity(playerIntent)
```

**docket** is a variable containing instructions to the activity of what media to play.

Here is the code from the manifest where both activities are defined:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.main.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
        android:name=".activity.player.PlayerActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_player"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"
        android:noHistory="true">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Changed `android:noHistory="true"` to  `android:noHistory="false"`.

Added this intent filter to player activity:

```
<intent-filter>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC"/>
</intent-filter>
```